# Woocommerce "Product URL" is overlaping with "Add to Cart" button

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have one weird issue. I just noticed that when check [into my store](http://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/), "add to cart" button is overlaping with product info url. To explain better check images bellow:

[image]

when point on red marked place point with cursor, is point to single product description. When i move add to cart button for 30px to top, then is causing overlaping with add to cart url and product description url, and add to cart button starting to be unaccessible. How to move add to cart button for 30px to top, and allign with price ?

When is insert this CSS:

```
#layout .woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce-page a.button, .woocommerce 
button.button, .woocommerce-page button.button, .woocommerce input.button, 
.woocommerce-page input.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit, .woocommerce #content input.button, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button
display: inline-block;
opacity: 1;
margin-top: 230px; // when change from 250 to 230 is see the issue !
margin-left: 55px;
color: #fff;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just try to give to your cart button  :

```
z-index: 100;
```

Comment: Thanks !! Works perfect !